# Kendo grid URL with html.actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid

I am trying to call controller action  MVC  from Kendo  grid row. 
Following is the the column

```
{
    field: "FileName", title: "Link2", width: "20%",
    template: "@Html.ActionLink('#=FileName', nameof(MeterFactorController.Document), new { Id = #=FileLocator }) )"           
},
```

It is displaying as string instead of URL.

Comment: You have an action with a file name? Anyway, you can't use javascript variables in razor/c# that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take user to a different View by calling the Controller method, you can try this:

```
template: "<a href='" + controllerUri + "/" + parameters + "'>" + Name of the link + "</a>"
```

If you want to make a Ajax call to the controller you can try the following:

```
template: "<a class='k-button' onclick='yourJSFunctionName(event,#=FileName#)'>Your Button Text</a>"
```

JS:

```
function yourJSFunctionName(event,FileName) {
    //Ajax call to the controller
    alert("Ajax call");
}
```

Hope this helps!